# sum two columns by query builder

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to add to numbers in codeigniter?
Below code

```
$this->db->where(array('is_active' => 1, 'time + duration <=' => time()));
$this->db->update('table', array('is_active' => 0));
```

will result in:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `is_active` = 0 WHERE `is_active` = 1 AND `time +` `duration` <= 1436170717
```

I want

```
`time` + `duration`
```

Answer (score 0):

I addded quotes between them and it worked.

```
$this->db->where(array('is_active' => 1, '\'time\' + \'duration\' <=' => time() ));
```